# How can I make buttons click at random

Tags: android, button, random, click

I have a menu with x number of buttons that all go to different pages the problem is I have to start at the button at the top n go down I'm order for it work without crashing. If I click on the second or third button without going to the prior buttons I get a crash. I'm not sure if this is the emulator or is there some java code I can put that will allow me to click any button at random? Thanks.

```
package com.android.nameofmyappy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Mainmenu extends Activity { 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

    Button Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bs);
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Bs.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

    Button Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pa);
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Pa.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

};
});
};
});
}
}
```

that is a part of the code i have more buttons that have different id and lead to diff pages successfully if i start at the top button and work to the bottom but i would like to be able to click on any button at random...

Comment: you should post some code so we can see what is going on.  You should be able to click any button by default if they don't interact with each other.

Comment: you don't need to click on the button, just call the method that handles the button clicked event, and pass null or fake arguments to them.

Comment: add your code under your question not in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to perform UI fuzzy testing (randomly interacting with all UI element, such as buttons) is monkey runner, you can use adb:

```
adb shell monkey -p <your app's package name> -v 500
```

This will randomly press anything 500 times to test against crashes.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for at the moment